# How to understand the URI `SASLibrary?*[@Name='L_EDW_DS'][DeployedComponents/ServerContext[@Name='SASApp']]`?

Tags: sas, uri, metadata

Trying to master URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) for meta data of SAS, I came across

```
 Libname EDW_DS META  LIBURI="SASLibrary?*[@Name='L_EDW_DS'][DeployedComponents/ServerContext[@Name='SASApp']]";
```

in code exported from SAS Enterprise Guide.

- Can anyone please explain it?
- Is the asterisk after the question mark a logical `or` operator, 
  relating the two `[...]` that follow it?
- Does anyone recognise the constructs in this URI from another query language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I explore the syntax bit by bit:

#### The basics

`ServerContext?*` lists all my servers, while `ServerContext?@name contains '_'` lists those with an underscore in their name. So the basic syntax is

```
<Object type>?<condition>
```

#### Combining conditions

Both URI below find the jobs with `CRS` as part of their name
and 'reserves' in their description :

```
Job?@Name contains 'CRS' and @Desc contains 'reserves'
Job?*[@Name contains 'CRS'][@Desc contains 'reserves']
```

So the construct `*[...][...]` works as a logical `and`.  `*` is a wild card and each `[...]` ads a condition

#### Involving related objects

The URI below finds the jobs with `CRS` as part of their name
that reside in a folder that contains `AML` in its name

```
Job?*[@Name contains 'CRS'][Trees/Tree[@Name contains 'AML']]
```

`Tree` is the object type in a folder in SAS Meta Data and `Trees` is the association type that relates a job to that folder. So now I see the above URI and the one in the question both have the structure

```
<Object type>?*[<Condition on object>][<Association Type>/<Related Type>[<Condition on Related>]]
```

Two more examples:

You find SAS Base libraries in meta data folders with '_IN' or '_OUT' as part of their name with

```
SASLibrary?*[@Engine ='base'][Trees/Tree[@Name contains '_IN' or @Name contains '_out']]
```

I mixed cases, just to illustrate the case insensitivity.

And this gives the Data warehouse libraries deployed on my server

```
SASLibrary?*[@Name contains 'DWH'][DeployedComponents/ServerContext[@Name='SASApp_MINE']]
```